# Decrypting a Header in Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-ssl

I am working on an application which accepts API Token. To be more secure, i want to ask the client (User or Another Application) to encrypt the API Token using their private key so that i can decrypt the same at Apache Reverse Proxy using the client's public key and forward to Tomcat.

I have some questions here:

1. How can i decrypt a header in Apache through a public key?
2. How do i enforce that my Apache only accepts Basic Auth or only Bearer Auth?

Answer (score 1):

Don't.

Use TLS to ensure that the token is secure in transit. Don't bother about securing it further, as it ***has*** to be available for the client and the server. Adding client side encryption won't increase security, but is extra code to be maintained for little or no gain.